# A method/device for measuring angles, as an experiment?

Tags: measurements

What's the best device for measuring angles, as an experiment for a fundamental physics lab at the university level?
The first experiment in our fundamental physics lab is "Measuring & Measurement errors". Currently we have four devices:
- rule (0.5 mm)
- Vernier Caliper (0.02 mm)
- Micrometer (0.01 mm)
- Spherometer

We're seeking for a method/device to find angles with high accuracy. There are some complicated optical devices/methods as in theodolites, but we want it to be economical and freestanding: Something with an obvious physics/mathematics basic for training aims.

Comment: Theodolites may be a complicated optical instrument, but I doubt that you could find a more accurate independent instrument. Also, what do you consider as economical? Some of the non-electronic versions are under $300.

Comment: Have you considered a sine bar?
http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/ten-inch-sine-bar-used-measure-angle-workpiece-measurement-set-shown-figure-4-height-gage--q1937431

Comment: @User58220, It seems a great method!